# How to update dictionary with if statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to create a histogram that is a dictionary showing for each wordlength how many words with that length are in the input text. So far I have managed to create a dictionary with all possible wordlengths, but I can't seem to manage to update the dictionary. I am stuck with the error: Full Python Traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-36-4ae1bb3ffd5e> in <module>
----> 1 text2wordlengthPDF("R095-Big-data-vrije-veilige-samenleving.txt")

<timed exec> in text2wordlengthPDF(text)

TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object
```

My code looks like this:

````
def text2wordlengthPDF(text):
    '''Read in the text document `text`, tokenize it using re.split and regex \W+, and create 
    the histogram of wordlenghts using the Counter method. Return this histogram. 
    The histogram is a dict showing for each wordlength how many words with that length are in the input text.'''

    #.read() is a way to retrieve strings from file object
    tokens = re.split(r'\W+', open(text, "r").read())
    tokens_counter = Counter(tokens)

    # create list of wordlength for items in Counter
    wordlength = list(dict.fromkeys([len(w) for w in tokens_counter ]))

    # Create dictionary with wordlength as key and occurrence as value
    dict_histogram = {i:0 for i in wordlength}
    for k,v in dict_histogram.items():
        if (k == len(w) for w in tokens_counter):
            k[v] = +1
    dict_histogram 

    print(dict_histogram)

# run and plot    
#pdf= text2wordlengthPDF(linktopdf())
#pdfS= pd.Series(pdf).sort_index()

#pdfS[pdfS>5].plot(kind='bar' ) #plot only the wordlenghts occurring more then 5 times.
#print(pdf) ```

#This is where I run my code with the input text
text2wordlengthPDF("R095-Big-data-vrije-veilige-samenleving.txt")
````

Comment: You probably want something like `if any(k == ...):`…?

Comment: The error is as follows: ``` TypeError: 'int' object does not support item assignment ```

Comment: Yes, because `k` is an integer. Because it comes from `for k, v in dict_histogram.items()`, so it's a key from a dict. It's unclear what you *want* this to do.

Comment: I want to update the value of the key in dict_histogram, *if* the len() of the key in the dictionary tokens_counter is the same as the **number** of the key in the dictionary dict_histogram

Comment: How are you importing `Counter`? I am trying to run your code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part

```
for k,v in dict_histogram.items():
    if (k == len(w) for w in tokens_counter):
        k[v] = +1
```

makes no sense. `k`, the *key* (length of each word) is not 'the' dictionary. (Besides, you probably meant `k[v] += 1`.)

Rewriting it more correctly would lead to

```
for k,v in dict_histogram.items():
    if (k == len(w) for w in tokens_counter):
        dict_histogram[k] += v
```

but that does not work. (I'm actually surprised that `if` line isn't a full-fledged syntax error. Is it valid syntax?) But the value `v` still holds the original *key* value there, which is `0` (from the initialization). You want `len(w)` there; but you can't, because it is a localized variable in the previous line only.

Rewriting that part in its entirety leads me to this:

```
import re
from collections import Counter

def text2wordlengthPDF(text):
    '''Read in the text document `text`, tokenize it using re.split and regex \W+, and create 
    the histogram of wordlenghts using the Counter method. Return this histogram. 
    The histogram is a dict showing for each wordlength how many words with that length are in the input text.'''

    #.read() is a way to retrieve strings from file object
    tokens = re.split(r'\W+', open(text, "r", encoding="utf8").read())
    tokens_counter = Counter(tokens)

    # create list of wordlength for items in Counter
    wordlength = list(dict.fromkeys([len(w) for w in tokens_counter ]))

    # Create dictionary with wordlength as key and occurrence as value
    dict_histogram = {i:0 for i in wordlength}
    for key,occurrence in tokens_counter.items():
        dict_histogram[len(key)] += occurrence

    pprint.pprint(sorted(dict_histogram.items()), compact=True)

text2wordlengthPDF("pslrm.txt")
```

getting the `key` as *word* from the counter, and so its value `tokens_counter[key]` is the number of occurrences. These can both be iterated over by the counter's `items()` function.
Then, this number is added to the dictionary, which is indexed by the length of each word. The final `sorted` lists the occurrences of lengths in ascending order:

```
[(0, 2), (1, 57262), (2, 54080), (3, 95251), (4, 132448), (5, 29969),
 (6, 62938), (7, 46593), (8, 23929), (9, 14645), (10, 12943), (11, 10708),
 (12, 2940), (13, 2742), (14, 1807), (15, 827), (16, 312), (17, 17965),
 (18, 91), (19, 118), (20, 147), (21, 24), (22, 35), (23, 7), (24, 13), (25, 1),
 (26, 24), (28, 1), (29, 24), (34, 1)]
```

(That 34-characters long 'word' just happens to be a random hex string in my test corpus, the PostScript Language Reference Manual: `4c47494b4d4c524c4d50535051554c5152`. Those other overly long words are just as uninspiring, alas.)

Comment: Thank you this helped me a lot to understand what I was doing wrong. I was able to solve the problem in a different way. This however took more lines that your solution. See my solution below.

   `# Create dictionary with wordlength as key and occurrence as value
    dict_histogram = {i:0 for i in wordlength}
    for word in tokens:
        for k in dict_histogram:
            if len(word) == k:
                dict_histogram[k] += 1
    return(Counter(dict_histogram))`

Comment: @JustinMensah: if you think it might help others, you are allowed to post your own solution as a proper answer. As a new contributor, you will have to wait a while but then you can even [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it as a solution for your question.